# convert ListView to ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, gridview

I am trying to render a LayoutBuilder in a code hereunder. This requires to convert ListView to ListView.builder as well as GridView to GridView.builder inside the LayoutBuilder. It seems using a map function would not be possible inside the item.builder. What is an overall approach for a convertion?

https://dartpad.dev/46d5b4ad7524b792ea9995bcc158eb0e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LayoutBuilder would look like :

```
         LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                return (isListViewOn && !isGridViewOn)
                    ? ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: hotels.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: Text(hotels[index].uuid),
                            title: Text(hotels[index].name),
                            subtitle: Text(hotels[index].poster),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 2),
                        itemCount: hotels.length,
                        itemBuilder: (cpntext, index) {
                          return GridTile(
                            header: Text(hotels[index].poster),
                            child: Text(hotels[index].uuid),
                            footer: Text(hotels[index].name),
                          );
                        },
                      );
              },
            )
```

The entire code would look something like. Note: I've hard-coded the data received from the URL in your code and re-created HotelPreview class  :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => const MyHomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool hasError = false;
  List<HotelPreview> hotels;
  String errorMessage;

  bool isGridViewOn = false;
  bool isListViewOn = true;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDataDio();
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> json = [
    {
      "uuid": "a9446b47-b0a1-454d-b89d-c3b848b7dc7c",
      "name": "B&B-La-Fontaine",
      "poster": "b&b_la_fontaine_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "64f4ecc6-368e-414e-b6fe-8a059affe1ca",
      "name": "Upon Lisbon Prime Residences",
      "poster": "upon_lisbon_prime_residences_2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "82aded74-373e-4b9e-b721-ebb938e9ac19",
      "name": "Disney Dreams",
      "poster": "disney_dreams_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "e08e35df-77a2-436a-9eb5-1dca46e0da00",
      "name": "Flora Chiado Apartments",
      "poster": "flora_chiado_apartments_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "d782a2bf-1055-482a-9e3f-dffe25f023bd",
      "name": "Golden Ratio",
      "poster": "golden_ratio_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "35344e37-ca0e-41a8-9c87-b13141d3e816",
      "name": "Grand Orlando Resort",
      "poster": "grand_orlando_resort_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0dd3c4e1-fb37-4348-aa06-7a2afc81c16a",
      "name": "Holiday Inn & Suites Orlando",
      "poster": "holiday_inn_&_suites_orlando_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "3a4dea4b-17c2-4c5a-8cb2-556af5c7091b",
      "name": "Motel One Brussels",
      "poster": "motel_one_brussels_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "ac1f829d-ffce-49d1-8ce6-9778559c98e5",
      "name": "New Rome House",
      "poster": "new_rome_house_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "44c84d52-a815-40f6-a47c-1b8782b3de6e",
      "name": "Oscar Hotel",
      "poster": "oscar_hotel_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "be338e29-d3dd-4298-924e-5604e8a7b350",
      "name": "P 17 Hotel",
      "poster": "p_17_hotel_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "85af46cd-ed99-4c9f-ba22-6e34ea5bb8da",
      "name": "Parkway International",
      "poster": "parkway_international_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "7fcd8e0c-fd4a-4146-bada-700e8790b69a",
      "name": "Stradom Apartments",
      "poster": "stradom_apartments_1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "b505a79c-0280-4a09-bba0-b984e1eed188",
      "name": "Upon Lisbon Prime Residences",
      "poster": "upon_lisbon_prime_residences_1.jpg"
    }
  ];

  getDataDio() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    // try {
    //   final response = await _dio
    //       .get('https://run.mocky.io/v3/ac888dc5-d193-4700-b12c-abb43e289301');
    //   var data = response.data;
    //   hotels = data
    //       .map<HotelPreview>(
    //           (hotelPreview) => HotelPreview.fromJson(hotelPreview))
    //       .toList();
    // } on DioError catch (e) {
    //   setState(() {
    //     errorMessage = e.response.data['message'];
    //     hasError = true;
    //     isLoading = false;
    //   });
    // }
    final data = json;
    hotels = data
        .map<HotelPreview>(
            (hotelPreview) => HotelPreview.fromJson(hotelPreview))
        .toList();
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      hasError = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Hotel Preview'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.view_list),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isListViewOn = !isListViewOn;
                isGridViewOn = !isGridViewOn;
              });
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.view_module),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isListViewOn = !isListViewOn;
                isGridViewOn = !isGridViewOn;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : hasError
              ? const Text('Page not found')
              : LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    return (isListViewOn && !isGridViewOn)
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: hotels.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: Text(hotels[index].uuid),
                                title: Text(hotels[index].name),
                                subtitle: Text(hotels[index].poster),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate:
                                const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                            itemCount: hotels.length,
                            itemBuilder: (cpntext, index) {
                              return GridTile(
                                header: Text(hotels[index].poster),
                                child: Text(hotels[index].uuid),
                                footer: Text(hotels[index].name),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                  },
                ),
    );
  }
}

class HotelPreview {
  String uuid;
  String name;
  String poster;

  HotelPreview({this.uuid, this.name, this.poster});

  HotelPreview.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    uuid = json['uuid'];
    name = json['name'];
    poster = json['poster'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['uuid'] = this.uuid;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['poster'] = this.poster;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this reference will help you to modify your code

**Listview with builder constructor**

```
ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: 5, 
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){ 
          return ListTile( 
            leading: Icon(Icons.list), 
            trailing: Text("GFG", 
                           style: TextStyle( 
                             color: Colors.green,fontSize: 15),), 
            title:Text("List item $index") 
            ); 
        } 
        )
```

**Gridview with builder constructor**

```
GridView.builder(
            itemCount: images.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3, crossAxisSpacing: 4.0, mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return Image.network(images[index]);
            },
        )),
```